# Twisted: how to silence certain log messages?

Tags: python, logging, twisted

I have XML-RPC methods in my application that generate a lot of Twisted log messages like this, which are in turn logged through Python's `logging` module:

`2011-09-08 18:00:51.399553 UTC INFO XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [08/Sep/2011:18:00:50 +0000] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.0" 200 129 "-" "xmlrpclib.py/1.0.1 (by www.pythonware.com)"`

These log messages are not necessary for me and I would like to either change them to level `logging.DEBUG` or suppress them entirely.  Is this supported?

**EDIT**: These are server-side log messages, being logged when I call methods of `twisted.web.xmlrpc.XMLRPC` objects.  These objects are used in a hierarchy (as in `putChild`) underneath `twisted.web.server.Site` and `twisted.web.vhost.NameVirtualHost` objects, and I'm using the default `SelectReactor`.  I suppose any of these classes or the request object could be the one actually logging these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`twisted.web.xmlrpc.Proxy` uses a factory to set up its HTTP connection (in the usual way).  The `noisy` attribute of the factories Twisted provides controls whether they log start and stop messages.  You can change the `noisy` attribute of `Proxy`'s factory like this:

```
from sys import stdout

from twisted.web.xmlrpc import Proxy
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python.log import startLogging

startLogging(stdout)

p = Proxy('http://localhost:8080/RPC2')
class QuietQueryFactory(p.queryFactory):
    noisy = False

p.queryFactory = QuietQueryFactory
p.callRemote('echo', 'foo')

reactor.run()
```

Compare to the output of the program when `noisy` is set to `True`.

For an XML-RPC server, the log messages come from the `twisted.web.server.Site` hosting the XML-RPC resource.  The `Site` initializer accepts a `logPath` argument; if you pass in a path for this parameter, then the request logs will be written to that path instead of to the main log.  You can also override the `Site.log` method which is what emits these log messages, to either omit just the ones you want to omit, or to do nothing to disable the request log entirely.

Comment: I should have specified that these log messages I want to silence are on the server side.  Apologies.  +1 anyhow because this is useful.  Is there a similar option that can be set for `twisted.web.xmlrpc.XMLRPC` objects?  I'm searching the 10.2 code and not finding anything.

Comment: Oops.  If I'd read the question more carefully I probably would have noticed that your example log messages was a server-side request log message, not a client factory start/stop message.  Updated the answer to talk about servers, too.

Comment: Cool.  Found the `log` method definition in parent class `twisted.web.http.HTTPFactory`.

Comment: (very similar case, hope to be helpful) with `twisted.web.jsonrpc` use `p.factoryClass` instead of `p.queryFactory` with equal successful effect.